Can we use Hedera JSON-RPC relay to deploy contracts and make signed transactions?
Got error while deploying smart contract in Hedera Hashgraph using local relay.
Hi, I'm trying to deploy a smart contract in Hedera Hashgraph using web3.js. We are running a JSON RPC relay in an EC2 instance. http://82.5.12.587:7546/
Got the following error during deployment. Could anyone identify the issue?
Error invoking RPC: (BUG) RequestType.fromCode() does not handle code: 88.
I changed the JSON-RPC endpoint to validationcloud and the contract gets deployed smoothly. Is there anything that needs to be changed in Hedera relay? Am I missing something?
[ Got the same error while sending send() and sendSignedTransaction()]
Thanks in advance

The IP address of the relay is incorrect. "587" is impossible, make sure you haven't made a typo.
